# Facebook Unity3d SDK doesnot include FBUtil and GameStateManager classes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk in my unity android game. I can not find FBUtil and GameStateManager in SDK downloaded from developer site.
I got the userId using FB.UserId. Also got the response

"`sending to Unity OnInitComplete({"access_token":"CAAUCMHNGlZCcBAHJBQAs7AoJNevkZAFbkpSRk60TURemvv4Y6IOu9NXjGcFjFRZAx9RoxwKT4ZBZASs0NLiYTmi4rl7RyWYdtxxhlKkSjoIWiqqDSBdSDKk0OppB2ZB4U6IgtqQs9PM8uNCaNF5xgqWn2c9DDkp4dJc9p38XONKpdwRF7qDHtM","user_id":"100003735696788","opened":true})`"

Just after that when I tried to get profile picture of the user, using the code given on developer.facebook.com,

```
void LoginCallback() {
FB.API (
    "/me/picture",
    Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,
    APICallback
);
```

}

The response I get is 4 question marks.

`????`

where is the problem? Please help..

Comment: The problem of `FileNotFoundException` has been resolved.
Now waiting for response from FB regarding missing classes FBUtil and GameStateManager.

Comment: Hi Nick,
Can you tell me which code snippet referenced these? In the meantime here are the files:

http://snipplr.com/view/72268/gamestatemanagercs/

http://snipplr.com/view/72269/fbutilcs/

Thanks for checking out the SDK!

Comment: Hi @aaron, thanx for the reply. The issue I was facing in getting profile pic has been resolved by using hardcoded link `http://graph.facebook.com/"+FB.UserId.ToString()+"/picture?type=large` since I am not getting right response from FB using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/FB.API/. The link you provided for the gamestatemanager and fbutil gives error `"The snippet you're looking for has either been deleted by its owner or it never existed to begin with."`

Comment: I suspect that FBUtil and GameStateManager are classes included in the Friend Smash demo app.  The docs where they are mentioned are in the Friend Smash tutorial
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/tutorials/games/personalize/

So just make your own versions of these classes if you need their functionality.

Comment: @NickMascarenhas, those links should be public now (incognito window works for me, at least), sorry about that.

The FB.API('/me/picture'...) should be supported but isn't, I'll make a task for that. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @aaron, Got it. I can see the code now. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron! This has been driving me nuts for 2 days trying to make the SDK work. I've been looking all over for the friend smash code referenced in the docs. The /me/... issues were making me crazy too. Thanks for being on top of this.

Answer (score 2):

I used this link using WWW in Unity and it worked well.. This is exactly what I did

1. Once you have the user id, create a WWW object like this:

`WWW url = new WWW("http://graph.facebook.com/INSERT_USER_ID_HERE/picture?type=large");`

1. Then in the LateUpdate I put an IF condition checking if the picture was loaded or not with a bool called loaded to avoid reloading the picture more than once

   ```
   if (url.isDone && !loaded)
   {
       loaded = true;            

       Texture2D textFb2 = new Texture2D(50, 50, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false); //TextureFormat must be DXT5

       url.LoadImageIntoTexture(textFb2);
       PLANE_OR_QUAD_OBJECT.renderer.material.mainTexture = textFb2;

   }
   ```

**NOTE: url is visible in the whole class as well as loaded**

If you need further help with this, let me know!

Comment: I got the profile pic using this. Also when I call `FB.API (
          "/me/picture",
          Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,
          APICallback
       );` 
I get response in delegate in undefined symbols like "???????"

Answer (score 1):

Normally Facebook picture API should return data with Texture type NOT text

For example, If you use code like @jkgm777 answer,

```
WWW url = new WWW("http://graph.facebook.com/INSERT_USER_ID_HERE/picture");
```

You should get Texture type that can use to replace your texture object in scene.
But If you want to get image url, USE THIS

```
http://graph.facebook.com/INSERT_USER_ID_HERE/picture?redirect=false
```

You will get this JSON for response

```
data: {
url: "{#IMAGE_URL#}",
is_silhouette: false
}
```